# mutate variable based on other columns with similar names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a df here (the desired output, my starting df does not have the Flag variable):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Person = c('1','2','3'),
  Date = as.Date(c('2010-09-30', '2012-11-20', '2015-03-11')),
  Treatment_1 = as.Date(c('2010-09-30', '2012-11-21', '2015-03-22')),
  Treatment_2 = as.Date(c('2011-09-30', 'NA', '2011-03-22')),
  Treatment_3 = as.Date(c('2012-09-30', '2015-11-21', '2015-06-22')),
  Surgery_1 = as.Date(c(NA, '2016-11-21', '2015-03-12')),
  Surgery_2 = as.Date(c(NA, '2017-11-21', '2019-03-12')),
  Surgery_3 = as.Date(c(NA, '2018-11-21', '2013-03-12')),
  Flag = c('', 'Y', '') 
)
```

and I want to derive the Flag variable based on these conditions:

1. For any column that starts with Treatment, set Flag to "" if Date = Treatment
2. For any column that starts with Surgery, set Flag to "" if Date = Surgery OR Date = Surgery +1 OR Date = Surgery - 1 (basically if the Surgery date is on the day, one day before, or one day after the Date variable, set Flag to "").
3. else set Flag = "Y"

I've looked into mutate_at but that rewrites the variables and assigns values of True/False.

This is wrong but this is my attempt:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Flag = case_when(
    vars(starts_with("Treatment"), Date == . ) ~ '',
    vars(starts_with("Surgery"), Date == . | Date == . - 1 | Date == . + 1) ~ '',
    TRUE ~ 'Y')
  )
```

UPDATE 2022-Aug-22

When I change a cell with the same date as the one in row 2:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Person = c('1','2','3'),
  Date = as.Date(c('2010-09-30', '2012-11-20', '2015-03-11')),
  Treatment_1 = as.Date(c('2010-09-30', '2012-11-21', '2015-03-22')),
  Treatment_2 = as.Date(c('2011-09-30', 'NA', '2011-03-22')),
  Treatment_3 = as.Date(c('2012-09-30', '2015-11-21', '2015-06-22')),
  Surgery_1 = as.Date(c(NA, '2016-11-21', '2015-03-12')),
  Surgery_2 = as.Date(c(NA, '2017-11-21', '2019-03-12')),
  Surgery_3 = as.Date(c(NA, '2018-11-21', '2012-11-20')),
  Flag = c('', 'Y', '') 
)
```

and then re-run the base R solution, the Flag in the second row is no longer "Y" but it should be as in that row, it doesn't meet any of the above conditions.

Comment: You may need `across`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` and `c_across` along with `any` for each condition in `case_when`. Then, we can make a list for the `Date` (and +1, -1 days) for `Surgery` to match.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Flag = case_when(
    any(c_across(starts_with("Treatment")) == Date) ~ "",
    any(c_across(starts_with("Surgery")) %in% c(Date, (Date +1), (Date-1))) ~ "",
    TRUE ~ "Y"
  ))
```

**Output**

```
  Person Date       Treatment_1 Treatment_2 Treatment_3 Surgery_1  Surgery_2  Surgery_3  Flag 
  <chr>  <date>     <date>      <date>      <date>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>
1 1      2010-09-30 2010-09-30  2011-09-30  2012-09-30  NA         NA         NA         ""   
2 2      2012-11-20 2012-11-21  NA          2015-11-21  2016-11-21 2017-11-21 2018-11-21 "Y"  
3 3      2015-03-11 2015-03-22  2011-03-22  2015-06-22  2015-03-12 2019-03-12 2013-03-12 ""
```

**Update**

Here is a possible base R solution that is a lot quicker than `tidyverse`. This could be done in one line of code, but I decided that readability is better. First, I duplicate the `Surgery` columns so that we have +1 day and -1 day, and then convert these columns to character. Then, I subset the `Treatment` columns and convert to character. I convert to character as you cannot compare `Date` with `%in%` or `==`. Then, I bind the date, treatment, and surgery columns together (`a`). Then, I use an `ifelse` for if the `Date` is in any of the columns but doing it row by row with `apply`, then we return `""` and if not then return `Y`. Then, I bind the result back to the original dataframe (minus `Flag` from your original dataframe).

```
dup_names <- colnames(df)[startsWith(colnames(df), "Surgery")]

surgery <-
  cbind(df[dup_names], setNames(df[dup_names] + 1, paste0(dup_names, "_range1")))

surgery <-
  sapply(cbind(surgery, setNames(df[dup_names] - 1, paste0(
    dup_names, "_range2"
  ))), as.character)

treatment <-
  sapply(df[startsWith(colnames(df), "Treatment")], as.character)

a <- cbind(Date = as.character(df$Date), treatment, surgery)

cbind(subset(df, select = -Flag),
      Flag = ifelse(apply(a[,1]==a[,2:ncol(a)], 1, any, na.rm = TRUE), "", "Y"))
```

**Benchmark**

[image]

Comment: this works great but in my data frame with many rows, this computes quite slow. Is there another way that works like this but can compute large data frames? Thanks!

Comment: @karuno Yeah, `tidyverse` is nice for readability, but it is generally not as fast as base R or `data.table` when working with larger datasets. I have added a base R option to my answer, which is much quicker than `tidyverse`.

Comment: I tested the base R function and I'm not sure if it works as expected. I think in the last line of code, in the ifelse statement, it's checking if the date is present in any of the dates in the entire cbind(treatment, surgery) dataframe, rather than a row by row comparison. I'll update my original post with an example.

Comment: @karuno Thanks for pointing that out; you are definitely right on with the error. I have added an `apply` statement, which should take care of that issue, and should be working properly now.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated to add data.table approach

If you want a data.table approach,  here it is:

```
df[melt(df, id=c(1,2))[,flag:=fifelse(
  (str_starts(variable,"T") & value==Date) | 
    (str_starts(variable,"S") & abs(value-Date)<=1),"", "Y")][
      , .(flag=min(flag,na.rm=T)), Person], on=.(Person)]
```

Output

```
   Person       Date Treatment_1 Treatment_2 Treatment_3  Surgery_1  Surgery_2  Surgery_3 flag
1:      1 2010-09-30  2010-09-30  2011-09-30  2012-09-30       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     
2:      2 2012-11-20  2012-11-21        <NA>  2015-11-21 2016-11-21 2017-11-21 2018-11-21    Y
3:      3 2015-03-11  2015-03-22  2011-03-22  2015-06-22 2015-03-12 2019-03-12 2013-03-12
```

I like Andrew's approach, but I was working on this when his answer came in, so here it is in case you are interested

```
df %>% inner_join(
  pivot_longer(df, cols=Treatment_1:Surgery_3) %>% 
    mutate(flag=case_when(
        (str_starts(name,"T") & value==Date) | (str_starts(name,"S") & abs(value-Date)<=1) ~ "",
        TRUE ~"Y")) %>% 
    group_by(Person) %>% 
    summarize(flag = min(flag))
)
```

Output:

```
  Person       Date Treatment_1 Treatment_2 Treatment_3  Surgery_1  Surgery_2  Surgery_3 flag
1      1 2010-09-30  2010-09-30  2011-09-30  2012-09-30       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>     
2      2 2012-11-20  2012-11-21        <NA>  2015-11-21 2016-11-21 2017-11-21 2018-11-21    Y
3      3 2015-03-11  2015-03-22  2011-03-22  2015-06-22 2015-03-12 2019-03-12 2013-03-12
```

Comment: Note, my proposed data.table approach is faster than the tidyverse approaches, and nice and concise, but still not as fast as Andrew's base R approach

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using `across` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Treatment"), ~as.numeric(. %in% Date), .names ="new_{.col}"),
         across(starts_with("Surgery"), ~as.numeric(. %in% c(Date, Date+1, Date-1)), .names ="new_{.col}")) %>% 
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(rowSums(select(., contains('new')))==1, "", "Y"), .keep="used") %>% 
  bind_cols(df)
```

```
  Flag Person       Date Treatment_1 Treatment_2 Treatment_3  Surgery_1  Surgery_2  Surgery_3
1           1 2010-09-30  2010-09-30  2011-09-30  2012-09-30       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
2    Y      2 2012-11-20  2012-11-21        <NA>  2015-11-21 2016-11-21 2017-11-21 2018-11-21
3           3 2015-03-11  2015-03-22  2011-03-22  2015-06-22 2015-03-12 2019-03-12 2013-03-12
```